# How do I print in multiple QLabel when I click the PushButton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I print in  multiple QLabel when I click the PushButton?, because it only works in Quantity I also want it in Item Name and Price. I tried putting multiple print_click(self) it wont work it say redefinition of unused 'print_clink'. Thanks in advance

**My Code:**

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot`

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ItemName = QLabel('Item Name:')
        self.Item_Line = QLabel('')
        self.Item_Name = QLineEdit('')
        self.PriceName = QLabel('Price:')
        self.Price_Line = QLabel('')
        self.Price_Name = QLineEdit('')
        self.QuantityName = QLabel('Quantity:')
        self.Quantity_Line = QLabel('0')
        self.Quantity_Name = QLineEdit()   
        self.Update_button = QPushButton("Update")
        self.Update_button.clicked.connect(self.print_click)
        self.Clear_button = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_click)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)  
        hbox.addWidget(self.ItemName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Item_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.PriceName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Price_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.QuantityName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Quantity_Line)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Quantity_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Update_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Clear_button)
        self.show()         
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Item_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Item_Name.clear)          
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Price_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Price_Name.clear)            
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Quantity_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Quantity_Name.clear)           
    @pyqtSlot()
    def print_click(self):
        self.Quantity_Line.setText(self.Quantity_Name.text())

    def clear_click(self):
        self.Quantity_Line(self.Quantity_Name.text(''))
        return self.Quantity


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of the expected result but I guess there are some mistakes and redundancies in your code :

- the `Price_Line` and `Item_Line` weren't added to the `QHBoxLayout`
- the method `print_click` wasn't setting the text from `Price_Name` and `Item_Name` on the respective `Price_Line` and `Item_Line`.
- the `clear_click` method wasn't really useful as you already connected the clear method of every other elements on that button.

The following code is adapted from yours, paying attention to the points mentioned above :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ItemName = QLabel('Item Name:')
        self.Item_Line = QLabel('')
        self.Item_Name = QLineEdit()

        self.PriceName = QLabel('Price:')
        self.Price_Line = QLabel('')
        self.Price_Name = QLineEdit()

        self.QuantityName = QLabel('Quantity:')
        self.Quantity_Line = QLabel('0')
        self.Quantity_Name = QLineEdit()

        self.Update_button = QPushButton("Update")
        self.Update_button.clicked.connect(self.print_click)
        self.Clear_button = QPushButton("Clear")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.ItemName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Item_Line)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Item_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.PriceName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Price_Line)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Price_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.QuantityName)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Quantity_Line)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Quantity_Name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Update_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.Clear_button)

        self.show()

        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Item_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Item_Name.clear)

        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Price_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Price_Name.clear)

        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Quantity_Line.clear)
        self.Clear_button.clicked.connect(self.Quantity_Name.clear)

    def print_click(self):
        self.Price_Line.setText(self.Price_Name.text())
        self.Item_Line.setText(self.Item_Name.text())
        self.Quantity_Line.setText(self.Quantity_Name.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```